# How to keep a button disable until all the text area is filled in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using react. I want to keep a button disable until all the text areas are filled. Once the all text areas are filled the button should enable. How can I achieve this ? and is it possible if I add validation for every input? I am adding my codes below. Thank you.

My codes are:

**App.tsx** :

```
interface IState {
  cName: string;
  cEmail: string;
}
class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cName: '',
      cEmail: ''
    }
    this.nameChange = this.nameChange.bind(this);
    this.emailChange = this.emailChange.bind(this);
    this.computeBmi = this.computeBmi.bind(this);
  }
  nameChange(nameValue) {
    this.setState({ cName : nameValue });
  }
  emailChange(emailValue) {
    this.setState({ cEmail : emailValue });
  }
  computeBmi() {
    // some code here
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div class="step_one">
          <TextInput label="Please confirm your full name?" placeholder="Full name" onChange={this.nameChange} />
          <TextInput label="Please confirm your email?" placeholder="Email ID" onChange={this.emailChange} />
          <MyButton label="SUBMIT" onClick={ this.computeBmi } />              
        </div>
        <div class="step_two">
          // some code
        </div>
      </div>
   )
 }
}


export default App;
```

**TextInput.tsx**

```
interface TIProps {
    label?: any;
    placeholder?: any;
    onChange(inputValue: string): any;
}
interface TIState {
    value: number;
    error: string;
}

class TextInput extends React.Component<TIProps, TIState> {

    constructor(props: TIProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            value : 0,
            error : ''
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        let inputValue = event.target.value;
        this.setState({ value : inputValue });
        this.props.onChange(inputValue);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <FormControl>
                    <TextField label={ this.props.label } type="text" placeholder={this.props.placeholder} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </FormControl>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TextInput;
```

**MyButton.tsx**

```
interface BIProps {
    label?: any;
    variant?: any;
    size?: any;
    color?: any;
    onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>;
}
interface BIState {
}


class MyButton extends React.Component<BIProps, BIState> {
    render() {
        return(
            <button className="myButton" onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                {this.props.label}
            </button>
        )
    }
}

export default MyButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `disabled` tag to the submit button with a ternary operation to check if the `nameValue` and `emailValue` states are empty. Something like this:

`<MyButton disabled={nameValue && emailValue ? false : true} label="SUBMIT" onClick={ this.computeBmi } />`